# incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'char' with an expression of type 'string' (aka 'char *'); dereference with

Tags: c, cs50

I am trying to convert an array to a char so that I may check whether it isdigit or not.
I had a look at some examples online. They showed that the conversion could be achived so:  `char myChar = argv[1];`

Where am I going wrong?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

string encrypt_string(string argv[]);
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // If user does not enter a command line argument(int), printf what they should do
    char myChar = argv[1]; //convert argv[1] to string to later check if it is alpha
        if (argc != 2)
    {
       printf("Usage: ./caeser key\n");
       return 1;
    }
    else
    {
         string cypher = encrypt_string(argv);
         printf("%s\n", cypher);
         return 0;
    }
}

string encrypt_string(string argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It should be `char *myChar = argv[1]`

Comment: Or `string myChar = argv[1];`

Comment: Ok, so `string` is several characters and `char` is a single one. How do you expect the conversion to work?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - I am only tryig to concert 1 character within the string. That being 'argv[1]'

Comment: `argv` is an array of strings, not of chars. So `argv[i]` is a single string (an array of chars), not a char.

Comment: argv[1] isn't a char, it is a pointer. cs50 string is a #define for char *. argv[1][0] would be a char.

Comment: @AdrianMole Okay... I got carried away with the equivalence... Taking down the comment... `:-)` Gotta stop wasting time with these _go nowhere_ comments and answers...

Comment: @AviBerger - this worked. Could you help furthure explain how `argv[1][0]` is a char. I am tring to understand betetr to help me with future applications.
Are tehre other instences where `argv[1][0]`  ( mainly the `[0]`) could be chnage to something else?

Answer (score 0):

"*Where am I going wrong?*"

Perhaps this will help you move forward...

```
#include <stdio.h> // From 'general' C language support...
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h> // ... to specific

string encrypt_string( string str ); // Use different names for clarity

int main( int argc, string argv[] )
{
    //  DO NOT TOUCH elements until you have checked they exist!
    //  char myChar = argv[1]; //convert argv[1] to string to later check if it is alpha

    // If user does not enter a command line argument(int), printf what they should do

    if (argc != 2) // Good
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caeser key\n");
        return 1; // good
    }

    //  else // Pointless! Where else is there to go?
    //  {

    // Note where argv[1] is used as a pointer to a string, passed to a function.
    string cypher = encrypt_string( argv[ 1 ] );
    printf("%s\n", cypher);

    return 0;
}

string encrypt_string( string str )
{
    /* Magic happens here, somehow */

    // return something valid... printf() doesn't like to print NULL...
    // return 0;
    return str;
}
```

Comment: DO you think that this change(to convert the string to a char) is a good chnage?

`// If user does not enetre a command line arguement(int), printf what they should do
    char myChar = argv[1][0]; //convert argv[1] to string to later check if it is alpha
        if (argc != 2 || isalpha(myChar))`

Comment: You cannot "convert" a string (that is an array of characters terminated with '\0') to A character... "Cat" does not fit into "c". You need to write a "loop" (eg for() or while() ) to test and/or process each character one-at-a-time... `isalnum()` will only test the single character that you pass to it, _not_ all the characters in any string.